# How do you account for zoom in a top down viewport?

Tags: mathematics, javascript, html-canvas, rpg, viewport

I've been stumped on this for days so please forgive me if this question is in bad-form. I have a generic top-down RPG structure, and I want to create a zoomable Canvas viewport for it. I've read several tutorials and I guess I keep messing it up somewhere.

[Current Codepen project here.](http://codepen.io/noxabellus/pen/yvjzt)

Relevant code from the project:

---

Camera:

```
function Camera(PARENT, CANVAS, SUBJECT, ZOOM)
{   
  this.draw = function()
  {
    var refs = [];

    Rect.call(this, SUBJECT.x, SUBJECT.y, CANVAS.width*ZOOM, CANVAS.height*ZOOM, "cen");

    for(o in PARENT.objects)
    {
      if(this.overlapping(PARENT.objects[o]))
        refs.push(o);
    }

    while(refs.length>=1)
    {
      var obj = PARENT.objects[refs.shift()];

      if(obj.draw)
        obj.draw(
          this.context, //Drawing ctx
          this.left, //Offset left
          this.top, //Offset top
          ZOOM //Scale factor
        );
    }
  };
}
```

Drawing function called by the Camera:

```
this.draw = function(context, offsetX, offsetY, scale)
{
  context.fillStyle = this.color;
  context.fillRect((this.left-offsetX)*scale, (this.top-offsetY)*scale, this.width*scale, this.height*scale);
};
```

---

How can I resolve the math here so that the zoom is correctly figured in to the drawing offsets?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can use the `scale` function on the context to handle zoom.

```
function drawAll(context, cameraX, cameraY, scale) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(cameraX, cameraY);
    context.scale(scale, scale);
    // Draw everything else
    context.restore();
}
```

This means you can draw each of your rectangles like this:

```
this.draw = function(context) {
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fillRect(this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);
};
```

Taking this approach means far less computations and a much easier way of manipulating the camera.

Comment: That is very helpful for optimizing, thank you! It wouldn't have fixed the problem I was having, but I'll add this in my answer, when I get the time.

Comment: I will just say that this will fix your problem and isn't just an optimization. It's just that it requires you to change your architecture (which is a little strange). Glad you found a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've fixed my problem. I was not accounting for the difference between the `CANVAS` size and the `ZOOM`'d canvas size. *I haven't yet fully optimized this,* but I'm posting it as-is, because I think it makes a good example for anyone having similar issues.

[Fixed Codepen fork.](http://codepen.io/noxabellus/pen/DxtpE)

Relevant changes to the code:

---

Camera:

```
function Camera(PARENT, CANVAS, SUBJECT, ZOOM)
{

  //...

  this.getRefs = function()
  {    
    this.refs = [];

    for(num in PARENT.objects)
    {
      var obj = PARENT.objects[num];

      if(this.projectedRect.overlapping(obj))
        this.refs.push(num);
    }

    return this.refs;
  };

  this.worldToScreen = function(x, y)
  {    
    if(!y&&typeof x == "object")
    {
      if(x.x!==undefined&&x.y!==undefined)
        y = x.y,
        x = x.x;

      else if(x.left!==undefined&&x.top!==undefined)
        y = x.top,
        x = x.left;

      else throw "worldToScreen Error";
    }

    return {
      x: (x-this.projectedRect.left)*(CANVAS.width/this.projectedRect.width),
      y: (y-this.projectedRect.top)*(CANVAS.height/this.projectedRect.height)
    }
  }

  this.screenToWorld = function(x, y)
  {
    if(!y&&typeof x == "object")
    {
      if(x.x!==undefined&&x.y!==undefined)
        y = x.y,
        x = x.x;

      else if(x.left!==undefined&&x.top!==undefined)
        y = x.top,
        x = x.left;

      else throw "screenToWorld Error";
    }

    return {
      x: (x*(this.projectedRect.width/CANVAS.width))+this.projectedRect.left,
      y: (y*(this.projectedRect.height/CANVAS.height))+this.projectedRect.top
    }
  }

  this.update = function()
  {
    var testRect = new Rect(SUBJECT.x, SUBJECT.y, CANVAS.width*ZOOM, CANVAS.height*ZOOM, "cen");
    if(!this.projectedRect||
       this.projectedRect.left != testRect.left ||
       this.projectedRect.right != testRect.right ||
       this.projectedRect.top != testRect.top ||
       this.projectedRect.bottom != testRect.bottom)
      {
        this.projectedRect = testRect;
        this.getRefs();
      }
  };

  this.update();

  this.clear = function()
  {
    this.context.clearRect(0,0,CANVAS.width,CANVAS.height);
  };

  this.draw = function()
  {    
    this.clear();

    this.update();

    for(num in this.refs)
      PARENT.objects[this.refs[num]].draw(this);

    PARENT.mouseLoc.draw(this);
  };
}
```

Drawing function called on the objects:

```
this.draw = function(CAM)
{
  var screenPos = CAM.worldToScreen(this);

  CAM.context.fillStyle = this.color;

  CAM.context.fillRect(screenPos.x, screenPos.y, 10, 10);
};
```